# Intersection $I \cap \mathbb{Z}$ where $I$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals, integers, finitely-generated

is there a reasonable algorithm that allows, given finitely many generators of an ideal $I$ of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, to find the intersection $I \cap \mathbb{Z}$?

Thank you.

Comment: Heuristically speaking, the task is to do elimination among the generators to see if you eventually get any integers or not. Of course this is problematic if the generators aren't monic, and even if they are elimination might produce new 'smaller' generators that aren't monic... But in principle you should be able to 'minimize' a set of generators to determine if any integers can be produced at all, and then it's matter of determining the ideal they generate together... (maybe I am describing what you have already thought about, but I have no way of knowing if you didn't type it.)

Comment: Thank you. For example with a lot of effort I proved that $(3x^2-x+1,4x^3-x) = (x-13,45)$ hence $I \cap \mathbb{Z} = (45)$, to do this I proceeded intuitively by repeatedly performing polynomial divisions after finding monic polynomials in the ideal... but I don't think this is easily generalizable.

Comment: Right, I agree. Given that this is the problem that must be dealt with sooner or later, I have a feeling there isn't any nicer answer...